# Failed to install ruby 3.1.0 on M1 - library not found for -lcapstone

Tags: ruby, apple-m1

linking shared-library libruby.3.1.dylib
ld: library not found for -lcapstone
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libruby.3.1.dylib] Error 1

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [Failed to install ruby 3.1.0 on M1 · Discussion #1933 · rbenv/ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1933), two approaches are possible:

1. Instruct the environment of where to look for the not-found libraries:

```
# Assuming Fish-shell, and that the two following directories are indeed present
# Adapting to Bourne affine shells is left as an exercise 
set -gx LDFLAGS "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/capstone/lib"
set -gx CPPFLAGS "-I/opt/homebrew/opt/capstone/include"

# relaunch the install process with installation manager
# rbenv install 3.1.0
# asdf install ruby 3.1.0
```

2. remove optional dependencies, capstone being "[used] in YJIT but only when `cppflags="-DRUBY_DEBUG"` is specified":

```
brew uninstall bloaty
brew uninstall capstone

# Adapt to fit local environment:
set -gx RUBY_CFLAGS "-w"
rbenv install 3.1.0
# asdf install ruby 3.1.0
```

And run the installation again by providing:

Comment: Please instead of simply linking to an external resource, explain the solution :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A shell-independent way of doing this: `env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/capstone/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/capstone/include" rbenv install ruby 3.1.0`. You also may want to use `brew --prefix capstone` to find the correct paths for your Homebrew installation.

Comment: Running the first two `set` commands (`set -gx LDFLAGS` and the other one) messed up my `zsh` setup. Just noticed the mention of the Fish shell after running them as I was in a hurry. Who uses `Fish` anymore? @LiamDawson Thanks for sharing the shell-independent way!

Comment: @Javad I use fish as my shell, which is why I like to have shell-independent ways of doing things.